# Allowing users input their "user" directory into a .jar installer

Tags: java, jar, windows-installer

```
public static void moveSQLite(){
        File source = new File("C:\\Users\\520\\Desktop\\System.Data.SQLite"); // Specify initial path
        File target = new File("C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\assembly\\GAC_64"); // Desired path

        // If the source location exists, delete the any old source files
        // and copy the entire directory of the source to the target location
        if(source.exists()){
            System.out.println("Installing SQLite Database.");
            try {
                FileUtils.deleteDirectory(target);
                System.out.println("Deleting previous versions of System.Data.SQLite");
                System.out.println("\"" + source + "\"" + " was successfully"
                        + " copied to " + "\"" + target + "\"");
                FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, target);
                System.out.println("SQLite database has been installed.");
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        // Otherwise prompt the user that the source directory does not exist
        }else{
            System.out.println("SQLite not found - are you sure you have it in the right directory?");
        }
    }
```

Above is an excerpt from one of the many methods used in my installer (which basically drags and drops files to specific locations in the user's computer). In the command-line, or preferably, in a user interface, I want to allow the user input their "source" directory, that is, in this case, my "user" directory is 520, but for other users, it may be different. Can I replace that with an asterix allowing Windows to figure out the directory itself, or do I have to have the directory hard coded? Anyone with software development experiences please input your answers - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I replace that with an asterix allowing Windows to figure out the
>   directory itself, or do I have to have the directory hard coded?

If you want any system to work out the user directory for itself (not just windows but any system) you can use

```
String homeDirectory=System.getProperty("user.home");
```

You can then create your own filestructure within the user's home directory **however** beware using `"foo\bar"` as "\" is not universal and will not work on all systems. However java comes to the rescue again with annother system property

```
String PATHSEPERATOR=System.getProperty("file.separator");
```

Then use like:

```
homeDirectory=homeDirectory+"foo"+PATHSEPERATOR+"bar";
```

You can then use this to create the `File` object

```
File homeDirectoryAsFile = new File(homeDirectory);
```

Comment: `user.home` would be, for example, where `520` is? Am I able to specify further into the directory, for example, `520\foo\bar`?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage I'm somewhat confused, do you want the system to figure out the users working directory and the user to enter some file structure inside the user directory?

Comment: Since the type for path is actually `Path`, and the output of getProprty() seems to be a `String`, isn't that an issue?

Comment: I'd like for the installation process as automated as possible. User would drag the installation package onto their `Desktop`, and through figuring out their `homeDir`, the installer does all the heavy lifting.

Comment: ok, but the code i've posted currently figures out the home directory, and applied whatever substructure you'd like to it. After that you can do whatever you'd like with that; copy things to it, whatever

Comment: Ok, let me see if I understand this correctly.

`homeDirectory+= "\foo\bar";` could work after `String homeDirectory=System.getProperty("user.home");
File homeDirectoryAsFile = new File(homeDirectory); `

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Exactly, glad to help. However, the "\" is windows specific (aka dangerous) on linux and mac I believe it is "/" instead. But java helps again with this. Use  String PATHSEPERATOR=System.getProperty("file.separator"); to get the system specific version and use +PATHSEPERATOR+ whereever you have used a \